# using $watch for change in html content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

How to use $watch for change in html content of a div. I tried with sample but its not working. It watches for the first time and whenever there is a change, the watch is  not triggered. Please find the code below

html

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
   <div editable-content></div>
  </body>
```

angular

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.directive('editableContent', function(){

return {
 replace: true,
 template:'<div contentEditable style="border:1px solid;width:300px;height:40px">this is 
 a div</div>',
 link: function(scope, element, attr){

  scope.$watch(function()

    {return element.html()}, function(value){

    console.log(value);

    });



  }


  };


});
```

Comment: You have to figure out what event triggers the change and call `$scope.apply()`. In this case, the watch would probably be redundant. Something like: `element.on('input', function() { $scope.$apply(function() {...}); })`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you should use isolated scope in your directive, have a variable for content and you easy to watch this variable change.

html

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
   <div editable-content></div>
  </body>
```

js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.directive('editableContent', function(){

return {
 replace: true,
 scope:{
      content: '='
 }
 template:'<div contentEditable content='content' style="border:1px solid;width:300px;height:40px">this is 
 a div</div>',
 link: function(scope, element, attr){

  scope.$watch(function()

    {scope.content}, function(value){

    console.log(value);

    });



  }


  };


});
```